# Scala FiniteDuration from String

Tags: scala, duration

Is it possible to parse a `String` into a `FiniteDuration` in Scala without writing custom code?

There is a method on `Duration`, called `create`, that accepts a `String`, however that produces a `Duration` and not sure how to further use it to create a `FiniteDuration` from it. There are a few factory methods on `Duration` that produce `FiniteDuration` instances, but those imply that I have to parse my string to produce their parameters (their signature expect a long and a `TimeUnit`).

These types I mention are from `scala.concurrent.duration`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the method you mention in order to create a `Duration` object (or simply use the `apply` method). Then, you can check if it's a `FiniteDuration` by `collect`ing it (since `FiniteDuration` is a sub-type of `Duration`), although there are several variants depending on your use case:

```
scala> val finite = Duration("3 seconds")
scala> val infinite = Duration("Inf")
scala> val fd = Some(finite).collect { case d: FiniteDuration => d }
fd: Option[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration] = Some(3 seconds)
scala> val id = Some(infinite).collect { case d: FiniteDuration => d }
id: Option[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration] = None
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Before I saw your comment I did this: `Duration.apply(myString).asInstanceOf[FiniteDuration]` but this implies that `myString` will always refer to a finite duration, so it's not bullet proof.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Scala 2.13 or above you can also leverage the [`isFinite`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/duration/Duration.html#isFinite:Boolean) method on [`Duration`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/duration/Duration.html) object to get `Option[FiniteDuration]`, with the help of [`Option.when`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html#when%5BA%5D(cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option%5BA%5D).

This is an example of how to do just that:

```scala
val dA: Duration = Duration("Inf")
val dB: Duration = Duration("48 hours")

val a = Option.when(dA.isFinite)(dA.asInstanceOf[FiniteDuration])
val b = Option.when(dB.isFinite)(dB.asInstanceOf[FiniteDuration])

println(a) // -> None
println(b) // -> Some(2 days)
```

You can also then write [implicit conversion](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) that will help you convert all `Duration`s to `Option[FiniteDuration]` like so...

```scala
implicit val durationToFinite: Duration => Option[FiniteDuration] = 
  d => Option.when(d.isFinite)(d.asInstanceOf[FiniteDuration])

val finiteDurationD: Option[FiniteDuration] = Duration("Int")
val finiteDurationE: Option[FiniteDuration] = Duration("48 hours")

println(finiteDurationD) // -> None
println(finiteDurationE) // Some(2 days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.toMinutes` and similar functions is also an easy solution.

```
FiniteDuration(Duration("48 hours").toMinutes, MINUTES)
```

Full example:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> FiniteDuration(Duration("48 hours").toMinutes, MINUTES)
res0: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 2880 minutes
```